# Automation of data loading to MySQL database from different data sources

Tags: mysql, database, etl

I have data in different sources like Access Database, CSV file, Flat file etc. and I need all these data in MySQL database. As it would be repetitive process, I need automation based on some trigger which will automatically pull the data, transform and load to MySQL database.
I am new to this area, so if anybody can suggest some good way or tool to achieve this. Any open source tools which can help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need an ETL tool such as SSIS. For SSIS alternatives to use with mySQL you could try:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloveretl/

I've not used any of the tools myself as I use SSIS, but there seems to be plenty of help out there on the net for them.

Answer (score 0):

Any **ETL tool** might help you with this (*CloverETL, SSIS, Petaho, Talend* etc.). I think some of them are out of the game since they are not open source (e.g. SSIS). The thing is that some of the parts you would like to do might not be easy to accomplish with just *open source / community versions* - e.g. automation, orchestration etc.

Speaking about the first product (*CloverETL*), you might need two products (*Designer and Server*). The **Designer is a client application** where you can design the whole data integration process using intuitive gui (it is basically oriented graph). Although the Designer can independently run the data integration graphs, it cannot handle the job orchestration, event based triggering. **Server**, on the other hand, **can handle all the event listening,** scheduled tasks etc.

If you are not familiar with any ETL tool you can take a look at these [Walk-through](http://www.cloveretl.com/learn/walkthrough/) videos.